# Java Applet lifecycle in Safari, not calling destroy()

Tags: java, macos, safari, applet, destroy

I'm doing some updates and bug fixes to a legacy web site consisting of a couple of pages (html documents) each displaying multiple java applets. Unfortunately I encounter weird issues when running on *OS X 10.9.1* and *Safari 7*. The problem can't be reproduced on Windows using *IE*, *Firefox* or *Chrome*.

#### How the problem is perceived...

When loading the first page every applet instance is loaded correctly and the page looks nice (well, as nice as it can get using applets). When I navigate to the next page only about half of the applet instances is loaded correctly and when I finally reach the third page no applet is loaded. If I instead open each new page in a new tab and then closes the old tab, the applets loads just fine.

#### What I have found out through debugging at the moment...

Looking at the network traffic through *Wireshark*, I can see that Safari downloads the jar file from the server when loading the page.

If I have the OSX *Activity Monitor* open I can clearly see that each applet instance is loaded into its own process. When navigating to a new page these processes are not shut down but instead new processes are opened until Safari reaches its maximum plugins per tab (or so it seems) and then no other applet instance is loaded until I switch tab or Safari is shut down.

Adding debug outputs to the `destroy()` method shows that it is not being called when switching page.

Is this a common problem when using applets on OS X and Safari? And do you have any solution, good or bad, on how to get this up and working as expected?

**UPDATE 2014-03-04**

The problem is reproducible using the following applet code

```
import java.applet.Applet;

public class Simple extends Applet {
    public Simple() {
        System.err.println("!!! SIMPLE()");
    }
    public void stop() {
        System.err.println("!!! STOP()");
    }
    public void start() {
        System.err.println("!!! START()");
    }
    public void init() {
        System.err.println("!!! INIT()");
    }
    public void destroy() {
        System.err.println("!!! DESTROY()");
    }
}
```

Running on OS X 10.9.1, Safari 7 and latest Java I can clearly see that the applet is initialized and started but never stopped or destroyed.